# Вывести дату завтрашнего дня на Python

Tags: python, if, условия

Нужно вывести дату следующего дня (например если ввести 15.12.20, то в результате будет 16.12.20) учитывая високосный год, но при этом используя только: `if`, `if–else`, `if–elif` и `if–elif–else`.
я начала делать, но думаю это не правильно, помогите пожалуйста.

```
d, m, y = int()
if d+1 and m and y>0:
    print(d+1, m, y)
```

Comment: совет: попробуйте для начала подумать на русском, а не на питонском - напишите алгоритм на словах типа "если дата равна 31, то... иначе если год весокосный то... иначе..."

Comment: Если использовать только условные операторы, то боюсь код будет весить как синий кит.

Answer (score 0):

```
CNT_DAYS = (31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)

day, month, year = map(int, input().split('.'))


v_year = year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0

max_day = CNT_DAYS[month - 1]
if month == 2 and v_year:
    max_day += 1

day += 1
if day > max_day:
    day = 1
    month += 1

if month > 12:
    month = 1
    year += 1

if day > 9:
    day_res = f'{day}'
else:
    day_res = f'0{day}'
if month > 9:
    month_res = f'{month}'
else:
    month_res = f'0{month}'

print(f'{day_res}.{month_res}.{year}')
```

Comment: Думаю мой код будет проще.

Comment: у вас в split() не передается "."
У меня код с большим количеством пробелов и полными названиями, поэтому ваш код меньше.
Так же у меня в конце стоят проверки, а у вас нет (когда дата 01.02.2022, у вас выводится 2.2.2022, а у меня 02.02.2022. У меня вывод имеет вид даты XX.XX.XXXX, а у вас X.X.XXXX) из-за этого мой код кажется сложнее.

Comment: ``print(f'{day_res:02}.{month_res:02}.{year}')`` и  проверки на количество знаков можно выкинуть

Comment: @knodr Вроде как исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос крайне странный, но если стараться абстрагироваться от всего кроме условных операторов то в торопях выходит как то так, а в целом не бойтесь использовать остальные особенности языков программирования помимо условных операторов.

```
d,m,y=map(int, input().split())

nd=(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)

if m==2 and d==29 or d==28:
    print(f'1.3.{y}')
elif d<nd[m-1]:
    print(f'{d+1}.{m}.{y}')
elif m==12:
    print(f'1.1.{y+1}')
elif d==nd[m-1]:
    print(f'1.{m+1}.{y}')
else:
    pass
```

**0.2**

```
d,m,y=map(int, input().split('.'))
nd=(31,29 if y%4==0 and y%100!=0 or y%400==0 else 28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)

if d<nd[m-1]:
    d+=1
elif m==12:
    exit(print(f'01.01.{y+1}'))
elif d>=nd[m-1]:
    m+=1
    d=1

if d<10:
    d='0'+str(d)
if m<10:
    m='0'+str(m)

print(f'{d}.{m}.{y}')
```

Comment: Ваш код не знает про високосный год. И else: pass бессмысленная конструкция

Comment: @Эникейщик позже изменю с улучшенным кодом, когда начал писать хотел заспидранить не вдумываясь.